# ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed sometimes returning false

Tags: wpf, clickonce

A WPF ClickOnce application occasionally returns False when checking IsNetworkDeployed. Usually uninstalling the app and reinstalling it again corrects this.

This is the code used to check the current version

```
Public Function ReturnCurrentVersion() As String
    Try
        Dim vBuild As String = "Debug"
        If System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
            Dim vVersion As Version = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
            Dim vAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            Dim vAssemblyName As AssemblyName = vAssembly.GetName()
            vBuild = vVersion.ToString
        End If
        Return vBuild
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return "Error"
    End Try
End Function
```

I can see other posts that relate to IsNetworkedDeployed returning false, but none of them appear to be just the odd intermittent issue as in this case.

Perhaps something odd happens during the install and it no longer sees itself as a ClickOnce app - but it would be useful to know why it's doing this.

Thanks

Comment: This happens to me as well btw